# Unable to lookup in current state: Shutdown

Tags: react-native, npm, ios-simulator

My dev env:

```
"expo": "~44.0.2",
"expo-app-loading": "~1.3.0",
"expo-asset": "~8.4.6",
"expo-font": "~10.0.4",
"expo-splash-screen": "~0.14.1",
"expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
"react": "17.0.1",
"react-dom": "17.0.1",
"react-native": "0.64.3",
```

I installed react-native and android emulator successfully.
But when I try to `npm run ios` (ios simulator) it shows me error message as below.

```
success Successfully built the app
--- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder, name:Any iOS Simulator Device }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:98977867-3902-4D23-B29C-08B6EB03844E, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 8 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:3174F921-AC58-4500-93FC-0027FF1D423E, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 8 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:E5C9DBFA-42D1-482F-8CEE-32CC9CEED9B1, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 8 Plus }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:9695CD6F-F4A9-4A27-8A7B-5BDA9CE3802D, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 8 Plus }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:0A2CDD11-A1F1-45EF-A02A-48611A4343CB, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 11 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:FA0F31DD-CEA2-4BF0-BCE3-87AE82824F12, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 11 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:3B080C68-9AB7-4F4F-8710-24FDC284717F, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 11 Pro }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:29B8556D-C01C-446D-A6B6-2475361AB10D, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 11 Pro }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:DBCA2C3E-713A-4679-B6F6-724326B664D6, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 11 Pro Max }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:A46A81B1-82AA-43B8-AC98-7A2B72C853F3, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 11 Pro Max }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:922326AE-B4B1-427C-8BD5-C0EE430B7B09, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:8921F3AA-29E6-49D6-876B-092FA51AE6AE, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 12 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:2BA9F9FF-E42E-42C5-8AC2-CB88740A02D3, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 Pro }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:79A4F630-6746-4F24-B68A-C951C2A8C42F, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 12 Pro }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:F0F3A8A1-232D-4701-AF22-428B6F5E4AEA, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 Pro Max }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:0D44D5D7-D3E3-4BE0-A6E0-17BF1FD66B23, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 12 Pro Max }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:170D47E7-0368-4878-9AD9-905A453A9AAA, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 mini }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:FC6B2408-8291-4CDA-AAE1-B6E9C15B474E, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 12 mini }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:92AE5C7B-8413-46E3-9FC6-94680D81214F, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:9B9EBA41-747A-4D42-8E43-E3424DFCFAE2, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 13 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:FD3C88DA-DD05-4973-A06E-F62B4FF4EC32, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 Pro }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:E190B2DC-4CE8-4D6A-86E6-667E6B95B156, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 13 Pro }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:A5383077-9ACD-46FE-9DA9-5E27358FA829, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 Pro Max }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:9A46D469-5F3A-40FD-B2F6-62045B978523, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 13 Pro Max }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:48395A6D-7B41-41C8-9399-3B0FAC509C0A, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 mini }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:ECCD9356-7DC5-4203-B851-C8325E79EEBA, OS:15.2, name:iPhone 13 mini }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:AE985F2D-5CA6-4904-AA68-EC7C5767C891, OS:15.0, name:iPhone SE (2nd generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:20AD6A97-39E1-4D9F-B7D9-98C287AD1BAD, OS:15.2, name:iPhone SE (2nd generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:0B64CE5F-2789-41D8-B544-58E53BE14215, OS:15.0, name:iPod touch (7th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:ABCC043D-D698-45F8-8AD3-454427CE8B9A, OS:15.2, name:iPod touch (7th generation) }
{ platform:macOS, arch:arm64, variant:Designed for [iPad,iPhone], id:FA486D26-719A-5166-83B5-4062F73F392B }
{ platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:4D271149-8105-44A1-B65A-F6CBFBC22C1F, OS:15.0, name:iPad (9th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:B7D33BBF-A8F8-4273-85F4-6514C04586E9, OS:15.2, name:iPad (9th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:D4F12306-4FCB-473A-BE06-04C4E07D0104, OS:15.0, name:iPad Air (4th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:A4FC57BF-5C0A-4F05-BAF2-0DF3DBDF2E33, OS:15.2, name:iPad Air (4th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:8841BB99-8C44-4B9E-82B4-A5B771CF5D45, OS:15.0, name:iPad Pro (9.7-inch) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:1A381559-3B8D-4299-BEB7-81AB0DFC1825, OS:15.2, name:iPad Pro (9.7-inch) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:46D29680-FB89-42A9-B0C4-F63E829EE1E5, OS:15.0, name:iPad Pro (11-inch) (3rd generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:CD54F638-D4C5-412D-827B-13595CD414C8, OS:15.2, name:iPad Pro (11-inch) (3rd generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:F7E02A62-42A2-408B-9055-3BC66F00E0AC, OS:15.0, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (5th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:1E434210-F9D6-4663-9EF9-178865719B9A, OS:15.2, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (5th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:A1799210-531E-4C6B-A0A3-190CD9599787, OS:15.0, name:iPad mini (6th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:88CA0E4F-98D7-4DC2-B2CA-AB4A249C6DA9, OS:15.2, name:iPad mini (6th generation) }
info Installing "/Users/hayat/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/noovies-bfderdwvhtcfcdaubuencjujxtyf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/noovies.app"
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, code=405):
Unable to lookup in current state: Shutdown
info Launching "org.name.noovies"
error Failed to launch the app on simulator, An error was encountered processing the command (domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, code=405):
Unable to lookup in current state: Shutdown
```

I tried almost everything as searching error `Unable to lookup in current state: Shutdown`.
delete cache from x-code, uninstall npm etc.. but nothing works.
please help me.

Comment: Are you want to migrate to `expo-dev-client`?

Comment: no I just want to execute ios simulator thru react native

Comment: Looking at your packae.json you're using Expo ? I'm right?

Comment: I just install react native as doc says but expo was installed automatically

Answer (score 0):

I have same question and I resolved it when I open project use Xcode. maybe it need Xcode env.